# Get the top host name of href on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link where I want to get the top level domain name of the domain clicked. 
In my example I have

```
    <a href="http://www.example.com/this/that">click on this link</a>
```

When I click on it I want an alert saying

www.example.com

I know window.location.host does this for the actual location of the site but am not sure how to get this for the individual href
I have tried the below but it returns

```
    jQuery(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(this).attr('href') || 'nohref';
        alert(window.location.host);
        alert(id);
    });
```

http://www.example.com/this/that

rather than
www.example.com

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward actually, no need for regular expression:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "a[href]", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(this.hostname);
});
```

See [MDN - HTMLAnchorElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement).

I'm not sure if it works in Internet Explorer though.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "a", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('href') || 'nohref';
    var domain = id.match(/http[s]?\:\/\/(.*?)[\/$]/)[1]
    alert(domain);
});
```

Comment: the regex will technically work but it's not very optimal. Also, attempting to use that `[1]` is going to throw an error if the regex doesn't match

Answer (score 1):

```
var domain = jQuery(this).attr('href').match(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+)/);
if (domain != null && typeof domain[1]!='undefined')
  domain = domain[1];
else
  domain = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a stab at using `document.domain`, although it's not as widely supported as `window.location.host`.

Comment: no. he is trying to extract the domain out of an anchor tag href attribute, not get the domain from the current page.